# Request for member '' in '', which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

I am trying to loop through a struct array and initialize its member "`history`", an int array, to `0` (Undoubtedly, you'll have a better suggestion than the one-value-at-a-time loop, which will be welcome, but that's not what the question is about).

I get an error not only I do not understand, but I cannot see how the multiple internet posts about it come into a function within my case.

The error is:

```
In function 'int main()':....
|error: request for member 'history' in 'coin', which is of non-class type 'coin_t [10]'|
```

This is my code (true copy-paste from a new project):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Hand input parameters
const int coinCount=10;
int weight[coinCount]={11,11,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10};
const int maxDepth=6;
const int caseCount=360;

// GLOBALS
struct coin_t
{
    float w;
    int history[maxDepth];
    int curDepth;
};

coin_t coin[coinCount];

int main()
{
    int i,j;

    //Initialize coin struct array
    for(i=0;i<coinCount;i++)
    {
        coin[i].w=weight[i];
        coin[i].curDepth=-1;
        for(j=0;j<maxDepth;j++) coin.history[j]=0; // Here's the error
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant `coin[i].history[j]`

Comment: Use a bit of caution with `_t` suffixes. They are reserved by POSIX. Not much of a problem if you're coding for Windows, but can cause problems just about everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coin` is an array of struct `coin_t` with sized `coinCount`. You need to access by `operator[]` for the corresponding element in the array.

```
coin[i].history[j] = 0;
//  ^^^
```

If you want to zero-initialize the `history` you could do better

```
struct coin_t
{
    float w;
    int history[maxDepth]{0};
    //                   ^^^^
    int curDepth;
};
```

by which you can skip the extra looping

```
    for (j = 0; j < maxDepth; j++)
        coin[j].history[j] = 0;
```

---

That being said C++ offers better [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Consider use if its suitable to the case.

Comment: I've even put the [] in the previous lines :S thanks